# Call to a member function create() on a non-object app\Controller\CarriesController.php line 5

Tags: php, cakephp

in app\Controller\CarrierController.php

```
<?php
class CarriesController extends AppController {
    public function index(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->Carries->create();
             if ($this->Carries->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your contact has been saved.'));
                 return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your contact.'));
            }
            }
        }

}
```

and the model it was 
**// Carriers.php**
////carriers is table name fields are inserted

```
<?php 
class Carriers extends AppModel{

    public $useTable='carriers'; 
    }
?>
```

finally the view app\View\Carries\index.cpt

```
<h1>welcome to Carriers</h1>
<br />
<br/>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Carriers', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>
<table>
<tr><h3>Register here</h3></tr>

<tr><td>F.Name</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->text('fname'); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>L.Name</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->text('lname');?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date Of Birth</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->date('dob');?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Degree</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->select('field', array('options' => array('B.E','B.sc','Mca','Mtech','Mba'),'empty' => '(choose)')); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Sex</td><td><?php
$options=array('M'=>'Male','F'=>'Female');
$attributes=array('legend'=>false);
echo $this->Form->radio('gender',$options,$attributes);
?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Carriers.Resume', array('between'=>'<br />','type'=>'file'));?></td></tr>

<tr><td><?php echo $this->Form->end('Apply');?></td></tr>



</table>
```

here getting error

Comment: For sure $this->Form isn't what you expect to be. Use xdebug or var_dump to see what it is.

Comment: This is why bake is great tool, you won't have errors like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Model names are singular

As indicated [in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html):

> Model class names are singular and CamelCased.

If you have a database table `carriers` the model name would be `Carrier`.

### Be conventional

The controller *file* is singular in the question, that will work if the url is `/carrier/xxx` (and the class exists) - as CakePHP doesn't apply any inflection magic to urls.

The expected url however would be: `/carriers/xxx` (i.e. the controller name is plural). In the question the file name is singular and the class name is a typo:

```
in app\Controller\CarrierController.php
                  ^^^^^^^
class CarriesController
      ^^^^^^^
```

CakePHP will not find classes in misnamed files, or use classes which are in the right place but misnamed =).

Answer (score 0):

Its a Camelcase name problem , 
otherwise if you want to keep it like that , you can simply load the model manually 
with

```
public function index(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->loadModel('Carriers'); 
            $this->Carries->create();
            // ...
        }
}
```

or

add this attribute to your controller ,

```
public $uses = array('Carriers');
```

good luck .

Comment: Model class names are singular and CamelCased.

Comment: yes absolutely , just considering what he done . this is a solution if he won't rename the controller or the Model